# XP Clients can't copy to networkshare

Tags: windows-xp, network-share, domain-controller, windows-server-2003-r2

i have a windows 2003 domain where i have strange problem. 
One of our file shares is on a 2003r2 domain controller, xp clients trying to 
copy files on the share are always getting the error

> error copying file or folder
>
> filename could not be copied. path too long

while windows 7 clients work fine.

Nothing unusal is found in the eventlog on both the server and the client.
It doesn't matter if i access the share by fqdn or ip, the path is including filename
shorter than 20 characters i.e. \path\share\file.txt

Copying files to other servers is fine. Reading from the shares is ok too.
Happened from one day to the other, one windows update that was installed this day ([kb2736233](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736233)) was removed but nothing changed.

thanks for any tips

Answer (score -1):

As the error states that the path is too long, I think it is because of the maximum path length of [260 characters](https://superuser.com/questions/14883/what-is-the-longest-file-path-that-windows-can-handle).

Comment: Did you read the question? He says the path is only 20 characters.

Comment: He states that the path is short, but it can be that the Full Path is longer. For example c:\some_long_dir_name_is_very_long\share\dir\file.txt can be very long also the user only sees \\computer\share\dir\file.txt. Or otherwise it can be d:\share\dir\file.txt could end as a share like \\some_long_computer_name_is_very_long\share\dir\file.txt. Another problem could be the filename encoding, while Windows7 can read and write UTF-8, Windows XP has problems.

Comment: Windows doesn't care about the underlying path, only the share path in this case. You can test this by using `subst` to make a really long path into a drive letter and then writing to it when you normally couldn't.